# How does the amount of Calcium Carbonate in blackboard chalk influence its quality

Tags: inorganic-chemistry

Does the amount of calcium carbonate in chalk influence its charecteristics ?
If so please mention them

Comment: Welcome to the chemistry site of the SE network.  

The site expects that you write explicit compact summary of your prior effort to answer the question, based on your knowledge and on searching for existing related  info or answers. It would prevent others to tell you what you already know or what you could easily find yourself. 

Effort not shown can be considered as effort not done and such a question may be  closed.  [How do I ask a good question?](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 1):

Amorphous pure calcium carbonate $\ce{CaCO3}$ is a white, common and rather soft mineral, called chalk or lime. It can be cut down in cylinders as thick as a finger. Using it on a blackboard will make a broad and thick line, and your fingers (and trousers) will quickly be full of white marks. It is too soft to be useful in a classroom. On the other hand, the same cylindrical pieces can also be made with plaster, which is hydrated calcium sulfate. But the obtained piece is too hard to be used on a blackboard. It will scratch the board. But if you make the appropriate mixture of plaster and lime, you can produce a piece of chalk useful on a blackboard.

So to produce a piece of chalk useful in a classroom, lime is reduced to powder, mixed with plaster ($\ce{CaSO4·\frac{1}{2} H2O}$). The mixture is then got wet. This will transform the plaster $\ce{CaSO4·\frac{1}{2}H2O}$ into gypsum $\ce{CaSO4·2H2O}$. This operation also transforms the mixture of two powders into a solid block, ready to be used for writing on a blackboard. Neither too soft, nor too hard.